# mostrar datos en una tabla

Tags: html, datatable, data, html-tabla

Cómo hago para que no me aparezca el disponible en la columna que ya figura no disponible, si lo hago con @else es peor ya que me recorre el array 3 veces.

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Hora</th>
      <th>Fecha</th>
      <th>Paciente</th>
      <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    @foreach($a as $x)
    <tr>
      <td>{{$x}}</td>
      @foreach($b as $z) @if($x == $z)
      <td>14:00</td>
      <td>Lopez</td>
      <td>no disponible</td>
      @endif @endfor
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>disponible</td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Resultado:

```
Hora    Fecha   Paciente    Status
10          disponible
12          disponible
13  14:00   Lopez   no disponible           disponible
14  14:00   Lopez   no disponible           disponible
15          disponible
16          disponible
17          disponible
18  14:00   Lopez   no disponible           disponible
19          disponible
20          disponible
```

Comment: No está claro a qué se refiere la pregunta. ¿Estás usando algún lenguaje, librería o framework?

Comment: ¿Que contienen tus variables?

Answer (score 1):

parece ser blade (plantillas) de laravel, y que te has liado con el if else
prueba esto:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Hora</th>
      <th>Fecha</th>
      <th>Paciente</th>
      <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    @foreach($a as $x)
{{-- por cada linea --}}
    <tr>
      <td>{{$x}}</td>
{{-- mostramos x en primer columna --}}

      @foreach($b as $z) 
{{-- por cada columna extra --}}
      @if($x == $z)
{{-- si x=z mostramos columnas paciente --}}
      <td>14:00</td>
      <td>Lopez</td>
      <td>no disponible</td>

      @else
{{-- de lo contrario mostramos columnas vacias + disponible --}}
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>disponible</td>
      @endif 
{{-- fin si x=z --}}
    @endfor
{{-- fin por cada columna extra --}}
    </tr>
    @endforeach
{{-- fin por cada linea --}}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pienso que te refieres a un `else`

```
   <table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Hora</th>
      <th>Fecha</th>
      <th>Paciente</th>
      <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    @foreach($a as $x)
    <tr>
      <td>{{$x}}</td>
      @foreach($b as $z) 
      @if($x == $z)
      <td>14:00</td>
      <td>Lopez</td>
      <td>no disponible</td>
      @else
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td>disponible</td>
      @endif
      @endforeach
    </tr>
    @endforeach

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Tambien recuerda cerrar tus foreach con `@endforeach`